# How to call String value from one class to another in Java

Tags: java, string

so in one class I have this string: `String LB = lcfield.getText();` to store whatever is written inside the `JTextField`. In another class I have a SQL statement where I need to use the same value as whatever is inside the `LB` string.

How to call this string?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside the class that owns the `JTextField`:

```
public String getLcfieldText() {
   return lcfield.getText();
}
```

And next to the SQL-statement, you can simply do:

```
String lcFieldText = fooView.getLcfieldText();
```

Comment: what is fooView? And if it`s public void, is it supposed to return anything? maybe it`s public String?

Comment: @user1703849 Wops, typo on my end. It's indeed supposed to be public String, edited. With fooView, I'm referring to the class which holds your GUI-code. In this case, the class which `getLcfieldText()` is placed inside.

Answer (score 0):

You have a couple of options.

One option is to make the String LB variable a static public variable of your first class, or private with a getter method to retrieve it.

The second option depends on how the first class creates an instance of your second. You could make a constructor that accepts a string value, which you would pass in when creating the object to call the sql.

I guess it depends on how you have you program setup. I have something like this in a swing program I wrote. I store the sql string in a public static String variable of my gui java class. Then when I need to execute the sql, I create an instance of the second class, then call it's sql method that takes a String parameter as input, which is where I pass my String value in to execute.

For example.
Class one has public static String mySql;
Class two has a method named executeSql(String sql);

After I create some sql in a string in Class one, I create an instance of Class two and call classTwo.executeSql(mySql);